# How to append lists from Selenium get attribute?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, dataframe, web-scraping

I'm new to coding and I finally got the data I want from the website. The problem here is I can't figure out how to get these into one DataFrame. I can't concat because these aren't assigned to a variable, it's just coming from the scraper.

Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
from csv import writer


from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys



chrome_options = Options()  
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://app.hedgeye.com/feed_items/all?page=1&with_category=33-risk-ranges")

#login
import requests
import sys

url = 'https://accounts.hedgeye.com/users/sign_in'
driver.get(url)

username = driver.find_element_by_id("user_email")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("user_password")

username.send_keys("")
password.send_keys("")

driver.find_element_by_name("commit").click()
#end login

for tr in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr"):


        data = tr.get_attribute("innerText")
        data2= data.split()[-3:]

        #makes the list rows not columns
        df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(data2).reshape(-1,len(data2)))
        print (df)  

driver.quit()
```

**Here's what the dataframe looks like**:

[image: Here's what the dataframe looks like]

**Here is what the scraper looks like before I put it into a dataframe and what the webpage looks like**:

[image: Final df]

[Final Product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsVIM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try initializing df outside of the for loop first. Then, df could be amended with each iteration with pd.concat.

So, outside the for loop you'd have something like:

```
df = DataFrame(data=None, index=None, columns=None, dtype=None, copy=False)
```

then after the data2 variable assignment:

```
df = pd.concat([df, DataFrame(data=data2.reshape(-1,len(data2)))])
```

Comment: I really thought that was going to work. I posted an image of the result. I believe I implemented it correctly

Comment: I see you added a new variable called df2 inside the for loop. Try instead to use the same df variable that you created outside the loop. df2 only holds what you assign to it on a particular iteration of the for loop. That's why you only have one row of data available. Since df is outside the loop, when you pd.concat(df...), it takes the original object and concatenates the new data to it.

Comment: Getting closer! Now how do I grab only the last dataframe created. Also, the index looks like its all zeros still so how do I get it to be one df?

Comment: If you want the dataframe containing all the data you added in the for loop, that'll be df. Just un-indent your print(df) statement (place it outside the loop) to see its final contents

Comment: Sorry for the newbie questions, but really helped man. Last on the agenda is how do I write this clean df (in most recent picture ) to a csv file everyday and keep it organized by date? I want to run this scrapper once a day (I think I can code that in) but if I do that as is I won't know what data goes with what date. Is there an easy solution?

Comment: Glad it helped. Any questions are okay when you're learning. As far as your other questions, if you've already done some research and can't find the answer, then it'd be best to post them in a new thread. That'll make it easier for others to find. If you're satisfied with this answer, please upvote :)